# How can I render bevel polygon on iPhone?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-2d

I checked out Tangram from App Store. How can I make this bevel effect on different shapes? What technology do I need create such a layout?

Do I need OpenGL ES or cocos2D maybe Quartz2D?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I've documented the development process of tangram!, find it here: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/categories/compactTangram/

At that time there was no option to render OpenGL polygons with anti-aliasing, so I made a demanding workaround to achieve the result (I wanted to add bump effect too, but later on I skipped). The point is in this post: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/02/04/compactTangram_074_-_organizing_textures_performance_preservingincreasing_plan/
Funny.

Since than, you can easily render with anti-alias, and retina also a solution for that pain, so some polygon mesh, some shader for specular stuff, and there you go, or go with Cocos2D, as you mentioned, it has growing 3D support.

Comment: You are really kind, köszi. ;-)

Comment: My first iPhone app. I'd do it elsehow nowdays.